# Blank letters only in menus

Tags: macos, netbeans, menu

I just installed NetBeans 11.2 and JDK 13 on my new laptop, a MacBook Pro (Sept 2019).

When I went to open a project only the letters in the selected item are shown.

[image: Blank letters picture]

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it out.

It was due to my MacBook settings, it was in dark mode.

This made the color of the letters in some menu's change to white.

i have changed dark mode to light mode and now everything is ok.